# How can i construct the destructiveChanges.xmlfile for Salesforce with the correct version?

Tags: salesforce

I  have a destructivechanges and package.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Package xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <version>51.0</version>
</Package>
```

Destructivechanges.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Package xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
   <types>
      <members>myCustomObject__c</members>
      <name>CustomObject</name>
   </types>
</Package>
```

I try to deploy this using the following code:

Here is the code i am using to deploy to Salesforce:
The .zip file was manually created via windows

```
        try
        {
            var zipBytes = File.ReadAllBytes(@"D:\delcustom\DelCustomObject.zip");
            var base64zipbytes = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Convert.ToBase64String(zipBytes));
            var resultDel = _metaService.deploy(base64zipbytes, new DeployOptions() { purgeOnDelete = true, singlePackage = true });
            var deployResult = _metaService.checkDeployStatus(resultDel.id, true);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
        }
```

When i look at the deployResult ,it says failed, but how can i know why it failed ,there is no detailed information in  regards to that and there is no exception ?

Answer (score 0):

In most cases, you should simply use the latest API version, which is 51.0 in Spring '21 and goes up by 1 with each release.

Only in rare circumstances should you use an older API version, such as when the syntax for referencing specific metadata components has changed and you wish to use the older version. I cannot think of a particularly good reason to do that; especially when deleting components, it's best to stick to the most up-to-date APIs.

Note also:

```
<members>DFB__ObjectToBeDeleted__c</members>
```

You cannot delete managed package `CustomObject` members (this item is part of the package with namespace `DFB`) unless they have been deleted by the package vendor.

Comment: I have tried with the latest API Version and even though I have specified only 1 custom Object to delete, it actually deletes all of them and even the flag purgeondelete doesnt actually purge , I still have to manually delete the deleted objects

Comment: If you have a specific problem please show your actual input in the question. The package shown should not delete more than one object, and in fact it's most likely to fail.

Comment: Yes I would show my input and code that i have attempted , but i cant seem to add formatted code via the add comment button...

Comment: Put it in your question by clicking Edit

Comment: So if it was a custom object I created , not DFB__ObjectToBeDeleted__c , I assume it should only delete that and only that custom object ?

Comment: Yes. You should absolutely not see all objects being removed. Destructive changes doesn't even support wildcards.

Comment: So with the code above and the xml file I dont know why this would happen . Any ideas  ?

Comment: I can't follow up any more tonight but I would really urge you to put all of the details in your question. Show the actual files you deployed, how you deployed them, and give specific details of exactly what happened.